# Fill in a polygon with texture/color using CCRenderTexture

Tags: opengl, textures, cocos2d-x

I have a concave polygon. The first thing I do is to triangulate it and store all triangle points in a vertex array.
I am trying to fill that polygon with texture or color but none of the two solutions work.

Here is the code when trying to get a texture with one color:

```
CCTexture2D* TextureTest::textureColorWithVertices(CCPoint* vertices,
                                                  int count,
                                                  CCRect spriteRect)
{
    CCRenderTexture *renderTexture = CCRenderTexture::create(spriteRect.size.width, spriteRect.size.height);

    renderTexture->beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 0);

    mShaderProgram->use();
    mShaderProgram->setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix();

    ccVertex2F* verts = new ccVertex2F[count];
    for( int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        verts[i].x = vertices[i].x + spriteRect.size.width / 2;//*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
        verts[i].y = vertices[i].y + spriteRect.size.height / 2;//*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    }

    ccColor4F* colors = new ccColor4F[count];
    ccColor4F red = ccc4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        colors[i] = red;
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    mShaderProgram->setUniformLocationWith4f(mColorLocation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, verts);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWS(1);
    delete[] colors;
    delete[] verts;


    renderTexture->end();

    return renderTexture->getSprite()->getTexture();
```

}

And the other one with a 256*256 seamless texture:

```
CCTexture2D* TextureTest::textureWithVertices(CCPoint* vertices,
                                             int count,
                                             CCTexture2D* baseTexture,
                                             CCRect spriteRect)
{    
     CCRenderTexture *renderTexture = CCRenderTexture::create(spriteRect.size.width, spriteRect.size.height);

     renderTexture->beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 0);

     mShaderProgram->use();
     mShaderProgram->setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix();

     ccVertex2F* verts = new ccVertex2F[count];
     for( int i=0;i<count;i++) 
     {
         verts[i].x = vertices[i].x + spriteRect.size.width / 2;//*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
         verts[i].y = vertices[i].y + spriteRect.size.height / 2;//*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
     }

     ccTex2F* uvs = new ccTex2F[count];
     float baseTexturePixelsWide = baseTexture->getPixelsWide();
     float baseTexturePixelsHigh = baseTexture->getPixelsHigh();
     for( int i=0;i<count;i++) 
     {
         uvs[i].u = ((spriteRect.size.width / 2 + vertices[i].x) / baseTexturePixelsWide) * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
         uvs[i].v = ((spriteRect.size.height / 2 - vertices[i].y) / baseTexturePixelsHigh) * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
     }

     ccGLBindTexture2D( baseTexture->getName() );

     mShaderProgram->setUniformLocationWith4f(mColorLocation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

     glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, uvs);
     glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, verts);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count);


     CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWS(1);
     delete[] uvs;
     delete[] verts;


     renderTexture->end();

     return renderTexture->getSprite()->getTexture();
 }
```

Finally I call these functions in this piece of code, rockPolygon is the original sprite:

```
    //Get the seamless square texture
    CCSpriteBatchNode* rockBatch = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("rock_small.png", kDefaultSpriteBatchCapacity);
    //Triangulate the old sprite
    vector<CCPoint> triangles = triangulateSprite(rockPolygon);

    //CCTexture2D* rockTexture = textureColorWithVertices(&triangles[0], triangles.size(), rockPolygon->getOriginalRect());
    CCTexture2D* rockTexture = textureWithVertices(&triangles[0], triangles.size(), rockBatch->getTexture(), rockPolygon->getOriginalRect());
    CCSprite* genSprite = new CCSprite();
    genSprite->initWithTexture(rockTexture);
    genSprite->setPosition(ccp(200,200));
    addChild(genSprite); //add generated sprite to main layer
```

I checked the triangulation, it works fine. I also remove all code between renderTexture->beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 0); and renderTexture->end(), set the alpha channel to 1 beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 1) and a white square is correctly displaying. So I guess the problem comes from the opengl calls but I can't find what is wrong. Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already on cocos2d 2.x. Your triangulation to convex shapes works. Then you can draw the shapes with CCDrawNode, no need to write your own render code.

Comment: I am using cocos2d-x 2.0.4 actually and CCDrawNode is available since 2.1. Btw I am also using a third party library that forces me to use derived classes from CCSprite for my polygons. Also, does CCDrawNode can be filled with a seamless texture by calling initWithTexture on it? Anyway i did some testing stuff and above code correctly works when calling it from another part of my code. So I'm investigating on what can cause this issue, but that is really strange, same code, two different calling locations, in one case it works, in another it does not. Thanks for answering me :)